# Android things: DP 7 retired PeripheralManagerService and I have issue with PeripheralManager

Tags: android, kotlin, iot, android-things, android-things-console

I have 1 project based on this: https://github.com/Nilhcem/i2cfun-androidthings
https://github.com/neuberfran/SmartDrive5 (the latter is my project)

But, when I change PeripheralManagerService to PeripheralManager (DP 7 and APi level 27)

```
 try {
            PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
            mDevice = manager.openI2cDevice(I2C_DEVICE_NAME, I2C_ADDRESS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access I2C device", e);
        }
```

I have this issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kXfknYcu4RUF7AT1549_sjJiVSG2_Jjo/view?usp=sharing  ***in this line:*** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nTXOV0qiQDe5XldzIuLsY26oIdyfs3x3/view?usp=sharing

I know about this: [PeripheralManagerService throws NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49141634/peripheralmanagerservice-throws-noclassdeffounderror)
but not solved.

Can you help me

Comment: You should update your device operating system and the library to version 1.0.0 as a number of APIs have changed or been updated.

Comment: @NickFelker How to I do this without necessarily pulling another install image and burning a sd card?

Comment: If you're still on the developer preview, your best bet is to install a new image. After that you'll be able to create new images and OTA update them to the device.

Comment: @NickFelker I create: OS version 1.0.1 (latest).  I can run motors with pio i2c I2C1 0x1B write-raw  0x46 128  0x05 0x00 0xD1. But 1.0.1 not exist and compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0' I have this issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OeDRh23QEr0utkWrDglhI9iNjS4Z6ABS/view?usp=sharing https://drive.google.com/file/d/10hCYyfJ0PGw0QflMiVjc12f-7B9h0Ryz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'  is the latest dependency. As you're seeing the permissions issue, you should add the permission to your manifest and then install the app again and then do a reboot.

Comment: @NickFelker I do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50752416/how-to-fix-java-lang-securityexception-caller-lacks-required-permission-com-goo see my manifest now pls: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eIJm0bSiaPSavNZQLZwcp_2Jet4lNTPv/view?usp=sharing  But now I have this issue:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18bife-nnTQU78o8yPsaDr2GUsrEUjP5T/view?usp=sharing and this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U6Dmw_i2YW-ZtHPYcndSc5sNNvJJdXXF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NickFelker, hI, Do you can help me more in question above

Comment: I solved with 3 changes: 1 - installed AT OS 1.0.1, 2 - put compileOnly 'com.google.android.things:androidthings:1.0'  in build.gradle (module), 3 - change:   try {
            PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
            device = manager.openI2cDevice(I2C_DEVICE_NAME, I2C_ADDRESS);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access I2C device", e);
        }          to:      device = PeripheralManager.getInstance().openI2cDevice(i2cName, i2cAddress)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class not found exception means that peripheral manager is not on the operating system. You are trying to use a new API on a device that has an older version.

You need to have the Android things library dependency in sync with the version installed on your device.

And as it has been suggested, you should get everything into the stable release.